# Align image with responsive text bootstrap

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, text-alignment

I have the following code for my image and text. However, when I decrease the size of the screen, the text does not stay in-line with the image on the left. Is there anyway to fix this?

```css
.media-body {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

@media (min-width: 544px) {
  .mt-0 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mt-0 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}

/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .mt-0 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
  
/* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .mt-0 {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <div class="pic1">
    <img src="images/mountain.jpg" class="align-self-start mr-3 img-fluid" height="400px" width="500px">
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">Weekend in the Mountains</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 you can use d-flex. With this we can remove `padding-top: 200px;` and simply add `d-flex align-items-center` to `<div class="media">`

Here is an example with the content being vertically aligned to center no matter what size the screen is: https://www.codeply.com/p/pyQF9H2qvG